# Strange wire on CO2 Laser Tube

Tags: lasers

[image]

Hello all, I just recently purchased a 40W CO2 Laser Tube. I noticed there is a weird stray copper wire coming out from the negative anode that is looped and tied around the lens frame. Can anyone explain what this is and its purpose? Is it safe to have it exposed like that, do I need to “cut it off”?

Comment: Negative (dc ground) is often run as case ground. Most cars connect negative battery terminal to the frame. Should be fine if positive voltage is carefully controlled.